# Gremlin repeat() query takes really long time

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, janusgraph

I have use-case where I need to get number of vertexes with specific type at each level till defined level.
For example:

> A has out Edges to B (admin), C (user), D(admin)
>
> B (admin) has out Edges to E(user), F(user), G(user), H(admin)
>
> C(user) has out Edges to I(admin), J(user), K(admin), L(admin),
>   M(admin)
>
> K(admin) has out Edges to N(admin), O(user), P(admin), Q(admin),
>   R(admin), S(user), T(user)

If levels = 3, and subject vertex is A the result should be (format can be different):

> level=1, users=1, admins=2, total=3
>
> level=2, users=4, admins=5, total=9
>
> level=3, users=3, admins=4, total=7

I have the query that does this for me but it's really slow because of repeat() when I have large data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
     Map<Object, Long> next = 
     graphTraversalSource.V().hasLabel(GraphDbConnection.USER)
           .has(GraphDbConnection.UUID, "uuidValue").until(loops().is(i)).repeat(out()) 
     .out().values(GraphDbConnection.MEMBER_TYPE).groupCount().next();
     MemberSponsorMetrics memberSponsorMetrics = new MemberSponsorMetrics();
     memberSponsorMetrics.setLevel(i + 1);
     int users = next.getOrDefault(UserType.USER.ordinal(), (long) 0).intValue();
     memberSponsorMetrics.setUsers(users);
     int admins = next.getOrDefault(UserType.ADMIN.ordinal(), (long) 0).intValue();
     memberSponsorMetrics.setAdmins(admins);
     memberSponsorMetrics.setTotal(users + admins);
     memberSponsorMetricsList.add(memberSponsorMetrics);
}
```

How can I achieve these results in efficient way? Is there any specific index types I can use or something else? I do have multiple basic indexes on vertex properties but I don't think they are useful here.

Comment: A goes to B and C, hence there are only 2 levels in your example, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I updated my data and also added one more for level 3

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Graph**

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV("person").property(id, "A").as("a").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "B").as("b").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "C").as("c").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "D").as("d").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "E").as("e").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "F").as("f").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "G").as("g").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "H").as("h").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "I").as("i").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "J").as("j").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "K").as("k").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "L").as("l").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "M").as("m").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "N").as("n").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "O").as("o").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "P").as("p").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "Q").as("q").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 1).property(id, "R").as("r").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "S").as("s").
  addV("person").property("memberType", 0).property(id, "T").as("t").
  addE("link").from("a").to("b").
  addE("link").from("a").to("c").
  addE("link").from("a").to("d").
  addE("link").from("b").to("e").
  addE("link").from("b").to("f").
  addE("link").from("b").to("g").
  addE("link").from("b").to("h").
  addE("link").from("c").to("i").
  addE("link").from("c").to("j").
  addE("link").from("c").to("k").
  addE("link").from("c").to("l").
  addE("link").from("c").to("m").
  addE("link").from("k").to("n").
  addE("link").from("k").to("o").
  addE("link").from("k").to("p").
  addE("link").from("k").to("q").
  addE("link").from("k").to("r").
  addE("link").from("k").to("s").
  addE("link").from("k").to("t").iterate()
```

Now the result you're looking for can be gathered using a single traversal, there's really no need to execute pretty much the same traversal over and over again (just changing the number of loops).

```
gremlin> g.V("A").
           repeat(out("link").
                  group("x").
                    by(loops()).
                    by(groupCount().
                         by(branch(values("memberType")).
                              option(0, constant("user")).
                              option(1, constant("admin"))))).
             times(3).
           cap("x")
==>[0:[admin:2,user:1],1:[admin:5,user:4],2:[admin:4,user:3]]
```

The keys of the outer map are basically the level minus 1.

This query takes about 1 ms over TinkerGraph. So unless your branching factor is much higher, you should get the results pretty fast. However, if the branching factor is high and your actually going to process thousands of vertices, you should consider to run this query in OLAP.

Comment: So, I think I forgot to mention couple things, "user" and "admin" are going to be values to vertex property (let's say key = memberType), and the value is not string, I just used it as string to explain the problem, they are integers (0 = user, 1 = admin). When you use groupCount().by('memberType'), it doesn't yield same output, it totals them all and returns "[0:[admin:7,user:5]]" using your example, replacing "by(label)" with by('memberType')

Comment: I ran both your query and mine with large data and the total time from my query running 7 times (7 levels) and your query running 1 times to achieve same results took similar time. - I am still not able to get array results back to get per level how you are showing, my results come back as summation of entire group (all levels) like "{0={1=1487, 2=185}}"

Comment: Check the update. I'm really nor sure what you meant by "it totals them all", that's not a behavior I've ever observed.

Comment: I am still getting them in totals for example - if i run the same query you posted against my data, instead of getting array with 3 levels, i get object with only 1 level but the values are total of all levels - " {0: {admin:11, user:8}} " so - admin = 2 + 5 + 4 and user = 1 + 4 + 3

Comment: I realized the problem, I am using JanusGraph and not Tinkerpop directly. I ran the same queries in tinkerpop console and it outputs the expected results as you provided. Not sure why using gremlin through janusgraph is different - any thoughts?

Comment: "you should consider to run this query in OLAP" - is it just using "g.withComputer()" or something else? For results of about 1300 vertexes, it took 15505 ms using "withComputer()" and 15736 ms without it. I don't see a big advantage.

Comment: 15 seconds sounds crazy slow to me. Is this with only 3 levels? Also not sure why you're getting the totals; perhaps create a Jira ticket for Janus.

Comment: I am getting 4 levels in 15 seconds, the result has 1300 users out of total 44,510 users in the database. I am using Janusgraph with dynamodb as backend storage

Comment: Still super slow. Unfortunately I can't explain why. Maybe it has to do with how your environment was set up? Is this all running within AWS or are you sending queries from your local machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156054/discussion-between-monali01-and-daniel-kuppitz).